# Conversion from a formatted date to a variable

Tags: php

```
$now =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date1=date_create($StartDate);
$date2=date_create($now);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%a");  //Difference in days, Es: 5
```

echo shows 5 as expected, but how can I now cast $diff into a variable like an int that I can use to make other numerical comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time PHP will automatically convert to an int when you use the variable in a numeric context. But if you want to do it yourself, use the `intval()` function.

```
$days_diff = intval($diff->format("%a"));
```